# Python scrapy working (only half of the time)

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, screen-scraping

I created a python scrapy project to extract the prices of some google flights.

I configured the middleware to use `PhantomJS` instead of a normal browser.

```
class JSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        try:
            driver.get(request.url)
            time.sleep(1.5)
        except e:
            raise ValueError("request url failed - \n url: {},\n error:
                  {}").format(request.url, e)
        body = driver.page_source
        #encoding='utf-8' - add to html response if necessary
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body,encoding='utf-8', 
               request=request)
```

In the settings.py i added:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
# key path intermediate class, order value of middleware
'scraper_module.middlewares.middleware.JSMiddleware' : 543 ,
# prohibit the built-in middleware
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None ,  } `
```

I also created the following spider class:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector

class Gspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google_spider"

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ["https://www.google.pt/flights/#search;f=LIS;t=POR;d=2017-06-18;r=2017-06-22"]
        self.prices = []
        self.links = []

    def clean_price(self, part):
        #part received as a list
        #the encoding is utf-8
        part = part[0]
        part = part.encode('utf-8')
        part = filter(str.isdigit, part)
        return part

    def clean_link(self, part):
        part = part[0]
        part = part.encode('utf-8')
        return part

    def get_part(self, var_holder, response, marker, inner_marker, amount = 1):
        selector = Selector(response)
        divs = selector.css(marker)
        for n, div in enumerate(divs):
            if n < amount:
                part = div.css(inner_marker).extract()
                if inner_marker == '::text':
                    part = self.clean_price(part)
                else:
                    part = self.clean_link(part)
                var_holder.append(part)
            else:
                break
        return var_holder

    def parse(self, response):
        prices, links = [], []
        prices = self.get_part(prices, response, 'div.OMOBOQD-d-Ab', '::text')
        print prices
        links = self.get_part(links, response, 'a.OMOBOQD-d-X', 'a::attr(href)')
        print links
```

The problem is, I run the code in the shell, and around half of the times I successfully get the prices and links requested, but another half of the time, the final vectors which should contain the extracted data, are empty.

I do not get any errors during execution.

Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening?
here are the logs from the command line:
[image: successful extraction]

[image: unsuccessful extraction]

Comment: Your request might be blocked every now and then. Or google has rate limited your requests. Anyways, I found [this API](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/) that might be useful. Rather than screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a very strict policy in terms of crawling. (Pretty hypocritical when you know that they constently crawl all the web...)

You should either find an API, as said previously in the comments or maybe use proxies. An easy way is to use [Crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera/). It manages thousands of proxies so you don't have to bother. I personnaly use it to crawl google and it works perfectly. The downside is that it is not free.